# Open Microsoft XAML Data Binding Sample in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, compatibility

When I try to open [this Data Binding Sample for Windows Store Apps](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Data-Binding-7b1d67b5) in VS 2013 Professional, I get a migration report saying that some of the project types are not supported.  Is there a work around for that?

EDIT: To make matters worse, apparently my MSDN subscription does not let me download VS 2010 professional.

Comment: What OS are you running ?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro, without the recent big update, which is not yet showing as "available" for me.